# Calling inherited functions and overriding behavior in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does this give this error -
'void D::func(const D &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const C' to 'const D &'

How to correct this, I want to call Base's func from Derived's func but note func is a friend function?

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout << "in C ctor" << endl;
    }

    friend void func(const C& abc1)
    {
        cout << "in C's func" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public C
{
public:
    D()
    {
        cout << "in D ctor" << endl;
    }

    void func(const D& abc)
    {
        func(static_cast<const C&>(abc));
        cout << "in D's func" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func(d);
}
```

why does this similar e.g. work though -

https://ideone.com/eNmvng

Comment: The problem is in `D` you've defined a member method called `func`, which hides the free function named `func` that is a friend of `C`. Inside `D::func` the name 'func' means `D::func`. To refer to the free function you need to write `::func` to look for the name in the global namespace. Alternatively declare `D::func` as a friend instead, which will make an overload of `func`.

Comment: @Kyle Now the first answer also makes sense to me, Thank you

Comment: The `func()` you're trying to call in `D::func()` is not a member of any class - it is a friend of `C`, and is in the unnamed/global namespace.   All you need to do is change `func(static_cast<const C&>(abc));` to `::func(abc)`.   This works because `D` is `public`ly derived from `C`, so a `const D&` can be passed to a function expecting a `const C &`.   And, by the way, that function does not belong to `C` (it is not a member) so is not inherited by `D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what that syntaxis does with function visibility, but this works:

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout << "in C ctor" << endl;
    }

    friend void func(const C& abc1);
};

void func(const C& abc1)
{
    cout << "in C's func" << endl;
}

class D : public C
{
public:
    D()
    {
        cout << "in D ctor" << endl;
    }

    void func(const D& abc)
    {
        ::func(abc);
        cout << "in D's func" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func(d);
}
```

---

Just for completeness sake, this works too:

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout << "in C ctor" << endl;
    }

    friend void func(const C& abc1)
    {
        cout << "in C's func" << endl;
    }
};

// Make function visible in global scope
void func(const C& abc1);

class D : public C
{
public:
    D()
    {
        cout << "in D ctor" << endl;
    }

    void func(const D& abc)
    {
        ::func(abc);
        cout << "in D's func" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.func(d);
}
```

Comment: This does works, Thank you, What does this syntax mean - ::func(static_cast<const C&>(abc)); what should i add in google in addition to scope resolution operator to learn more about this?

Comment: @user123456 If you move forward with this I suggest using a different name for one of the `func` definitions. Chances are you may not need to use a friend function anyway so I would rethink what you're trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious what does the ::func syntax mean? when and why is :: used in front of function calls?

Comment: `::` denotes global scope.

Comment: The `static_cast` is unnecessary, since `D` is publicly derived from `C`.

Comment: @Peter Sure, fixed.